# Adding job I quickly left for a better option on LinkedIn

Tags: resignation, linkedin

I left an industry job after 2 months for an academic one I liked more (both are data science/bioinformatics field).
It was on good terms, I got along well with the team and I think I contributed to the project.

I worry about leaving so soon might make me seem like an unstable hire in the future, or at least having to explain my reasons at every interview.

But on the other hand, it was valuable experience in an industry setting and I feel being hired by that company makes me seem more desirable.

Would it be better to put it on my LinkedIn/CV or leave it off? Since it's two months, it wouldn't look like too big of a gap.

Comment: It's similar, but I think the fact that the job in that post was a toxic environment makes it different enough for a post. I wouldn't be having the same dillemma in that situation.

Comment: Welcome new user.  It's probably better if you mention the general field. (Example, programming, chef, medical etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be better to put it on my LinkedIn/CV or leave it off?

Two months is very few time to consider it a "proper" work experience. It may raise more doubts/questions than make you look more desirable (yes, you will surely have to explain that in each interview).

Most likely it will be best to leave it out, specially if it does not relate very closely to the jobs you pretend to seek/apply. If you plan on applying to more academic jobs... including experience on another, unrelated area (industry) will not add much to your CV.

Some exceptions to my last paragraph are Internships, which are *usually* shorter and ok to include when you have few to none related past experience (i.e., your first job(s)).

Of course, leaving it out doesn't mean it won't show up on Background Checks, and you should always be prepared to explain/justify it if prompted.

Answer (score 1):

I think a CV should be honest, after all it ***is*** experience and it sounds good that you left on good terms. You could describe the job and the reasons why you left and it could be a talking point in an interview.

Comment: I'm a little unsure why a two month job should be included out of honesty [but a 3+ year PhD should be omitted](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/170863/104563).

Comment: See [my comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/170668/unemployed-for-a-year-interviewer-says-they-want-someone-with-more-experience/170863?noredirect=1#comment555391_170863) about this. @DavidW